# Getting a DropDownList's SelectedValue in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, drop-down-menu

Here is what I am trying to achieve here:

I have a DropDownList which selects the (student) class. On selecting the same, a grid view is generated. After which the next DropDownList has to be selected with which period needs to be updated with Present/Absent. A calendar tool is also present to set the date.

The grid is being generated perfectly, and I have used a blend of setting columns to visible when a particular period is selected. So as of now, below is the result.

Here is the snippet of the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYUOr.png

So in the page, I have selected the period 2 which is why the column P2 is showing up with a Item Template of DropDown. Below is the GridView code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RollNo" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RollNo" SortExpression="RollNo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RollNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RollNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P2" SortExpression="P2">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Present</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Absent</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P1" SortExpression="P1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Present</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Absent</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, when I try to update the DB I am unable to select the "DropDownList3.SelectedValue" in the .cs page.

I need this value to be updated on the database with a single click of button called update.

Comment: pls try: Loop all row of gridview=> find control with ID DropDownList3=> get value of dropdownlist

Comment: I am unable to open snippet from http://i.stack.imgur.com/NYUOr.png. Can you please double check the link?

Comment: can you please check the image here --> http://postimg.org/image/bf222kl6r/